# iOS didEnterRegion sometimes not get called

Tags: ios

I am working on xcode 8.3.3 on a project written in Swift2.3.
I installed SwiftLocation (2.3 Branch) library via Cocoapods in order to monitor region events (didEnter/didExit Region).

I had 3/4 region to monitor on average at the same time
I add them as it follows:

```
do {
    let monitor = try Beacons.monitor(geographicRegion: epicenter, radius: 100, onStateDidChange: { (state) in
        state == .Entered ? self.delegate?.checkedIn(id, status: .Awake, onFinish: nil) : self.delegate?.checkedOut(id, status: .Awake, onFinish: nil)

   }) { (error) in
        let error = NSError(domain: “Monitor”, code: error._code, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : error.description])
        self.delegate?.failedBecause(error)
    }

   monitor.onAuthorizationDidChange = { status in
        self.delegate?.movedTo(status)
    }

} catch let error {
    let error = NSError(domain: “Monitor”, code: error._code, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : error as! AnyObject])
    self.delegate?.failedBecause(error)
}
```

I have activated Background Modes and asked for Authorization and I am sure it is working in background because the app is woke up and I am able to get events even if the app has been killed.
Moreover both the gps and the internet coonection on the device are turned on. The feature seems to work well, but often the callback “onStateDidChange” of the method “Beacons.monitor(:)” doesn’t get called. It’s really weird that I have a great number of exit event, but not too many entrance.

We already tested if this situation occurs only because the device was inside the region when monitoring was added but this seems to be not the reason. How is possible to have sometimes only the exit event but not the entrance? To intercept the exit event, the system knows that the device was inside the region, but the entrance event hasn’t been triggered.
Any help on fix this or debugging it is really appreciated.

Hi @Gero. Thanks for your answer.
Your scenario is likely to happend.
I simulated it on the XCode Simulator either killing the app directly or waiting more the 5 minutes with the app in background (since Apple documentation suggests that background tasks are killed after 3 minutes). In both situation `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` is not empty and it tells me that the app has been woken up.

In this case, I execute a piece of code that just instantiate the `LocationManager` and set the controller as delegate without restarting regionMonitoring.
I have evidences on the server side that `didEnter/didExit` is called via this flow. I know this because the app makes an HTTP call to store the event and sends “asleep” as a parametern to distinguish it from the “standard” flow in which it sends “awake”.

For this reason I am afraid that this is not the reason, because it would be still not clear why it is sometimes working and sometimes not.
We’ll make a try with `requestState(for:)` and let you know :wink:

Comment: Which is it then? iOS or Android? Please refrain from adding tags that are unrelated to your question

Comment: You must provide the code and the configuration you are using that gives you trouble.

Comment: Can you please specify what you did to test it in foreground and background? How are you verifying that didEnterRegion is called or not? I.e. what does your app actually try to do in that method?

Comment: @Gero I'm using `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to intercept `launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]`. I created an istance of `CLLocationManager`, set a delegate and intercept the delegate methods `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion`. When the app intercept one of this delegates from this flow, it make an http request with the timestamp and the state (asleep or awake).

Comment: @FrancescoClementi I faced a similar problem awhile back as well with region monitoring and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548000/ios-region-monitoring-not-working) is what I ended up doing.

Comment: Terminating the app and waiting 5 minutes is something different: If you kill it via 2 times Home button and "swipe it out", no location updates will be sent and the app won't be re-awoken (by iOS design). Just waiting 5 minutes will not necessarily really terminate the process (even if it does, iOS still shows it in the task manager, instead check the process list in Xcode's Debug menu). It will stay in suspended mode. From there, `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` is not called! The LocationManager will be restored on entering background, however (when region updates arrive)

Comment: @Gero This is true for location update, but it seems different for region monitoring. Apple says: `regions associated with your app are tracked at all times, including when the app isn’t running. If a region boundary is crossed while an app isn’t running, that app is relaunched into the background to handle the event. Similarly, if the app is suspended when the event occurs, it’s woken up and given around 10 seconds to handle the event.`  [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html)

Comment: That's exactly my point. You cannot easily test this, as you usually only put the app into background/suspended mode. Having it terminated by the OS is what I assume causes the issue. "to handle the event" might still imply you need to check the region yourself, without the callback.

Comment: @Gero Thanks, I got the point ;) I'll try your suggestion and I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is only an educated guess, but since it's too long for a comment I'll try to warp it into an answer. Your comments and (excellent) edit indicate to me you know what you're doing and employ the correct methods (sidenote: A lot of questions on this topic result from improper understanding of the feature, so at first I thought it's maybe that).

What I could imagine happens is this:
The app is running while you're outside of the region, i.e. the next thing would be a `.Entered` kind of state in the callback. However, the app gets terminated by the OS before that happens for some reason (memory?).

Next you enter the region, so the app gets relaunched. You properly figure this out checking for the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` in the `launchOptions` dictionary and start your region monitoring again. However, I *think* the system might then not explicitly deliver the state change via callback again. The documentation is not that clear on this for region monitoring. So now you're inside the region, but never received an according state change callback.

The solution would be to explicitly query the region if and only if your app is (re)launched with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` using `requestState(for:)` of `CLLocationManager` and your region (this might be tedious if you have multiple regions, but is probably required).

---

**Edit**: For what it's worth I stumbled over a related question on the [dev forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/240578) and even clarified the issue further there. Gualtier Malde from the Apple staff answered, so that should be a valid source. In case the link vanishes (as sometimes seems to happen), here a summary and quotes of what he explained.

The basic question was about rebooting (which terminates an app) and then the app not getting region updates. His first answer was

> After a reboot, your app will not be alerted for iBeacon events until the user unlocks the device first. There is no way around this.
>
> If you are having issues with iBeacon detection even after the user unlocks the device, barring any coding problems with your app, the first place to look at is the iBeacon advertising, and to make sure it is advertising 100% to the specs, and is also calibrated properly for its installed location.

I then further asked when exactly the resume is about to happen. I wanted to know whether because of this it's theoretically possible to *miss* region updates and when exactly the region updates should come in again. Answer:

> Yes, your app should get relaunched in the background - considering the beacons are advertising correctly, Bluetooth is turned on, etc. - without user interaction.
>
> All this will happen only after the first unlock. Nothing will happen with your app after a reboot until after the first unlock.
>   Any events that happen before the first unlock can be considered lost to your app.

From this I take that even a relaunched app gets region updates. I have no idea why you miss any, unless you actively reboot the device.

One thing to note regarding your testing procedure though:
Putting the app in background and waiting > 5 minutes will **not automatically terminate the app**. It will usually simply put it into the suspended state. The documentation you refer to does indeed explain that background tasks are terminated after a certain time (note that they do not guarantee a definite time here, Apple stays intentionally vague here to remain in control for future changes and stuff), but that **does not mean your app process is necessarily killed**! The tasks are just ended and your app is suspended. There is no real way for us to have the OS terminate an app. AFAIK it would do that if it needs the resources, but that's hard to enforce somehow. Besides, I am also pretty certain that a debug build on a development device (especially connected to Xcode/the debugger) doesn't necessarily behave like an iPhone in the wild. The simulator behaves even more different.

All that said, I am even more surprised that you get an `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` call, because the way you described how you terminated the app shouldn't even result in it being terminated in a regular, okay way. Maybe you do have a bug, it crashes (or even gets "punished-quit" by the OS?) or the like? I don't know if an app that for example tries to "maliciously" buy background processing (e.g. by answering the `application(_:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)`'s completion handler dishonestly or something?) time might be exempted by the system from region updates? That might be the case, but we're way beyond the scope of this question. It all boils down to an application state issue, i.e. life-cycle problem. You have to be very careful to properly identify what state you're trying to debug and expect to be in.

Comment: Hi @Gero I edited my question to answer you because it was too long.